# Two test-case is not running present in same describe giving error "No Such session" in protractor

Tags: protractor

When i try to run two test cases("it") in protractor present in same describe block, it gives error "Failed: no such session" while starting of second test case although first test case is running good but not second one using protrcator

Comment: Could you provide the actual code in both cases? Thanks.

Comment: Try using firefox instead of Chrome

Comment: Would you like to share your `conf.js` code and your spec file so we can better help you?

Comment: @QualityProducts i have tried with firefox also but their i am getting error:
 Failed: waiting for page to load for 10000ms.
even without starting a browser it throws above error with firefox.
conf.js capability:
 capabilities: {
   'browserName': 'firefox',
   browser_version: '39.0'
    },
if i run test-case individually then they are working fine.

Comment: Can u post ur code?

Comment: @Quality Products check the code for confi.js

exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,
  capabilities: {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,
  browser_version: '50.0'
  },
   framework: 'jasmine2',
   specs:['spec.js'],
   onPrepare: function() {
        browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50000)
   },   
   jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 300000, 
     onComplete: null,
     isVerbose: false,
     showColors: true,
     includeStackTrace: true,
   }
}

Comment: and spec.js


spec.js

describe('google search', function() {
beforeEach(function() {
    browser.get('http://www.google.com');
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
   });
   
   afterEach(function() {
    browser.driver.close();
   });
  it('verify title', function() {
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Google');
   });
  it('search tutorial', function() {    
    element(by.xpath('//div[@id='sb_ifc0']')).sendKeys('Tutorial');
    element(by.spath('//input[@type='submit' and @value='Google Search']')).click();
   });
});

Comment: Provide formatted code in your question. Adding it in comments makes no sense.